# calling openmp or threadpool in a thread lead to memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, openmp, threadpool

I met a problem, there is no any problem when I using a thread-pool(https://github.com/bshoshany/thread-pool) or openmp to parallize for loop in main, but when I use a consume-produce thread model, using a thread-pool or openmp in the product thread will lead to memory leakying, any suggestion to solve this problem.

I have a scan camera to scan many sub-images(like 1920x1200) , and merge these image to a big images(beyond 60000x60000); Finally, divide the big images into many tiles and save them to disk;

To speed up thie program, I create two thread, one thread get the sub-images from scan camera, the other merge these sub-images to a big image(using openmp or threadpool to speed up), divide big image and save to disk(using openmp or threadpool to speed up);  I use Opencv library to process image

simple brief code like that:

```
template <typename T>
class QueueFPS : public std::queue<T>
{
public:
    QueueFPS() : counter(0) {}

void push(const T &entry)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);

    std::queue<T>::push(entry);
    counter += 1;
    if (counter == 1)
    {
        // Start counting from a second frame (warmup).
        tm.reset();
        tm.start();
    }
}

T get()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    T entry = this->front();
    this->pop();
    return entry;
}

float getFPS()
{
    tm.stop();
    double fps = counter / tm.getTimeSec();
    tm.start();
    return static_cast<float>(fps);
}

void clear()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    while (!this->empty())
    {
        this->pop();
    }
}

unsigned int counter;

private:
    cv::TickMeter tm;
    std::mutex mutex;
};
// Frames capturing thread
 QueueFPS<std::vector<cv::Mat>> framesQueue;
```

in produce thread

```
 std::thread framesThread([&]()
                                    {
            cv::Mat frame;
            while (row_count_gen<numRows)
            {
                std::vector<cv::Mat> arr_img(numCols);
                #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(numThreads)
                for(int col_cnt=col_start; col_cnt<col_end; col_cnt++){                    
                    std::string img_path = img_path_base + "/" + to_string(row_count) +"_" + to_string(col_cnt) + ".jpeg";
                    arr_img[col_cnt] = imread(img_path);
            }

            framesQueue.push(arr_img);

            row_count_gen++;
        } });
```

in the consume thread:

```
std::thread processingThread([&]()
                                    {
            while (row_count < numRows)
            {
                   // copy all arr_img  and merge to big image
                   #pragma omp parallel for
                    for (int col_cnt = 0; col_cnt < numCols; col_cnt++)
                    {
                        arr_img[col_cnt].copyTo(merge_img_oneRow(big_rect_position));
                    }

                    #pragma omp parallel for
                    for (int row = 0; row < rowTileNum; row++)
                    {
                        for(int col=0; col<colTileNum; col++)
                        {
                              string save_path = to_string(row)+"_"+to_string(col)+".jpeg";
                              cv::imwrite(save_path, merge_img_oneRow(rect(col*tilesize,row*tilesize,tilesize,tilesize);
                    }

            }
});
```

Comment: Why do you mix `std::thread` and `OpenMP`? I suggest using one of them. Are you sure that all the functions you call are threadsafe (`imwrite, copyTo, imread`, etc. )?

Comment: I have to use consume-produce thread model, all these functions come from opencv.  Honestly, I'm not sure they are threadsfe, but guaranted that image data have no read and write conflicts. I just wonder calling openmp or threadpool in std::thread will lead to memory leak or not, and potential method to solve this problem, thanks

Comment: The comment about only using the OpenMP API should be investigated further.  OpenMP does support the consumer/producer paradigm via OpenMP tasking. You'd have the main thread (the one starting up main() :-)) do a parallel region with a single that would spin and create a new task for each item produced.  Then in this task would can use taskloop constructs (or other tasking constructs) to parallelize that task further.